# PECL/Memcache and PECL/Memcached

Tags: php, mysql, memcached, pecl

I have both PECLs installed in my PHP setup, and when I do `php -V` I can see both running. In my `/etc/php5/conf.d/` folder both of these PECLs are enabled. When I checked `phpinfo`, then I came to know `PECL/Memcache` is used as it had the assigned port number `11211`.  Both PECLs have their own config in `.ini` files but only one is used. I know we cannot use both at a time, but I want to test both PECLs one at a time. My question is how to test these PECLs without deleting anyone, by just changing the settings. I want to test Memcache and disable it and test Memcached before deciding what to use. Is there any way I can accomplish it without having to delete ?

Currently I am using [PhpMemcachedAdmin](http://code.google.com/p/phpmemcacheadmin/) to check Memcached, its still in beta and buggy. If anyone could suggest me some other better tools then It'd be really helpful.

Comment: What is the goal of your testing?  You should *probably* just use Memcached, as it uses the new-era official library.  The old Memcache extension uses an older generation of library, and exposes fewer features.  Both are still actively maintained.

Comment: My goal is to use more reliable and fast caching solution. I know memcached uses `libmemcached` library, but [Here it says](http://brian.moonspot.net/php-memcached-issues), it leaks connections while using persistent connection. So, I was looking to test both before deciding which one to use. Memcached definitely have advantage of `CAS`, but its hard to decide which one to use without testing.

Comment: Do keep in mind that the blog post you linked was made two years ago, so they've probably fixed the problem by now.  Hopefully...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have both extensions active at the same time. Both, `PECL Memcache` and `PECL Memcached` are PHP **clients** connecting to a Memcached **server**.

Concerning the pros and cons

As said before, Memcached build upon [libmemcached](http://libmemcached.org/libMemcached.html) which is maintained by the the memcached server team. People say it's better, but I could not verify this to that day.

PECL memcache still has the better PHP session support.

I found (a bit older, but mostly still valid) comparison chart [here](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/PHPClientComparison)

**EDIT**

PHP is using either of the extensions to connect to the Memcached server.
Here are some usage examples

***PECL Memcached usage example in PHP***

[PECL Memcached class reference](http://php.net/manual/de/class.memcached.php)

```
// create PECL memcached Object
$m = new Memcached();

// add a server, connection is established lazily as far as I know
$m->addServer( 'localhost', 11211 );

// set values, those are written into your server's memory using the memcached server
$m->set( 'integer', 1 );
$m->set( 'intIncrement', 1 );
$m->set( 'intDecrement', 1 );
$m->set( 'string', 'I am a string' );
$m->set( 'array', array( 'a', 'b', 'c' ) );

// increment
$m->increment( 'intIncrement' );

// decrement
$m->decrement( 'intDecrement' );

// get values again
var_dump ( $m->get( 'integer' ) );
var_dump ( $m->get( 'intIncrement' ) );
var_dump ( $m->get( 'intDecrement' ) );
var_dump ( $m->get( 'string' ) );
var_dump ( $m->get( 'array' ) );

// delete values
$m->delete( 'integer' );
$m->delete( 'intIncrement' );
$m->delete( 'intDecrement' );
$m->delete( 'string' );
$m->delete( 'array' );

// close connection
$m->close();
```

***PECL Memcache usage example in PHP***

[PECL Memcache class reference](http://php.net/manual/en/class.memcache.php)

This can be in the same PHP script!

```
// create PECL memcache object
$m = new Memcache;

// connect to the memcached server
$m->connect('localhost', 11211);

// set values
$m->set( 'integer', 1 );
$m->set( 'intIncrement', 1 );
$m->set( 'intDecrement', 1 );
$m->set( 'string', 'I am a string' );
$m->set( 'array', array( 'a', 'b', 'c' ) );

// increment
$m->increment( 'intIncrement' );

// decrement
$m->decrement( 'intDecrement' );

// get values again
var_dump ( $m->get( 'integer' ) );
var_dump ( $m->get( 'intIncrement' ) );
var_dump ( $m->get( 'intDecrement' ) );
var_dump ( $m->get( 'string' ) );
var_dump ( $m->get( 'array' ) );

// delete values
$m->delete( 'integer' );
$m->delete( 'intIncrement' );
$m->delete( 'intDecrement' );
$m->delete( 'string' );
$m->delete( 'array' );

// close connection
$m->close();
```

You can also store objects into memcached, check out this article about [object serialization](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php) and the [magic class methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) `__sleep` and `__wakeup()` in PHP

As you can easily see, the basic usage of both clients, PECL Memcached and Memcache is pretty identical.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I might not be clear in my question, I wanted to ask how to configure `Memcached server` to use `pecl Memcache` once and `pecl Memcached` another time. I guess `Memcached` doesn't use `both pecls` at a same time.

Comment: Added two usage examples along with some more info and reading material. I hope this can solve your confusion

Answer (score 1):

There wasn't any specific way to do this. I had to delete the symlink of one of the configuration to use other. Instead of deleting the whole `.ini` file, only deleting symlink sounds viable option, as deleting the symlink the `pecl` becomes inactive.

Comment: how about commenting the `extension=memcache.so` part? Please stop posting wrong and undocumented things. That is not the correct way to disable a extension. That is why you have differend files in the php.d directory, so you can enable/disable the extension as you like. And beside that, memcache and memcached extensions work perfectly fine together.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about commenting the line. But what's the use of having both enabled if you are using just one ?

Answer (score 0):

I must have missed the part with "cannot use both at the same time". Who gave you that idea? They are two separate extensions, with separate functionalities/objects.

Skipping the above, memcached is a lot better to use, because it implements a lot more functionality than the memcache extension (cas is one of them that i have used recently and comes to mind).

Second thing: persistent connections? Why would you do that? Memcache can support a lot of connections, it is built for that. There is no need for persistent connections. We are having over 2k hits on same memcached server without a problem in a production app.

PS: "When I checked phpinfo, then I came to know PECL/Memcache is used as it had the assigned port number 11211" is wrong. There is no port associated with a extension. A php extension is not a daemon/service in itself (although you can definitely build one in php). It is actually more likely that 11211 is the default port for a memcache server, and not a actual port.

Comment: you can have both `pecls` enabled at same time, but `Memcached daemon` would be assigned to use just one. So, my question was how to use one pecl once and change to another after testing it. And you took my `phpinfo` completely out of equation, or I might not be clear on that part. I can see both pecls enabled in `phpinfo` and the `memcache pecl` has the extra information attribute consisting port number of `Memcached daemon`. I hope I am clear now.